# Планирование заданий в oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть таблица

```
create table users (
  login varchar(20) primary key not null,
  status number default 1 check(status>0 and status<4) not null
);
```

А также job:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name     => 'delete_service',
    job_type     => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action   => 'DELETE FROM users where status = 3',
    start_date   => sysdate,
    end_date     => to_date('01.01.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=1;'
  );
END;
/
```

По моей логике он должен срабатывать каждую минуту с данного момента, т.е. удалять каждую минуту пользователей со статус = 3.
Я добавил пользователя со статусом 3 и до сих пор жду когда это сработает, что я делаю не так? Может быть в sysdate не хранится время, а только дата?

Answer (score 3):

Если заглянуть в [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300), видно, что там у всех разновидностей процедур параметр `enabled` по дефолту стоит `FALSE`. Соответственно, вам надо передать туда `TRUE`, чтобы джоб включился:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name        => 'delete_service',
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'DELETE FROM users where status = 3',
    start_date      => sysdate,
    end_date        => to_date('01.01.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=1;',
    enabled         => true  -- теперь должно заработать
  );
END;
/
```

А пока он у вас просто выключен.

Далее вторая ошибка - у вас JOB описан как PL/SQL блок, а по факту там просто SQL запрос. Так что вам надо еще код блока подправить. Вместо

```
DELETE FROM users where status = 3
```

напишите

```
begin DELETE FROM users where status = 3; commit; end;
```

Тогда будет совсем хорошо.